# Ubuntu Boot Slow - Late Drive Access

Tags: boot, 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

So I just installed Ubuntu on a brand new Samsung 840 Pro SSD and have noticed that it is slower than expected. The LED access light doesn't start blinking until after 20 seconds or so have passed, after which the boot up seems to actually start. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

I have Windows 7 installed on a separate SSD and use Windows Loader as the main loader. Windows Loader points to GRUB2, from which I then start Ubuntu up. The 20 seconds count that I mentioned earlier starts AFTER I select Ubuntu 14.04.1 from the GRUB2 menu.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I have only one partition for / and /home. I intend on using a shared NTFS drive for my documents and other personal files, so I had no need for the /home. I did not make a /swap since I have 12 GB of RAM. I also did not make a /boot since I was told that it's not really necessary in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I figured it out. Turns out a USB SD card reader that I had plugged in was causing that delay. It was also causing the delay in Ubuntu detecting my keyboard upon startup. I unplugged it and it works fine now.